# My brand new HP notebook won't boot Ubuntu 12.10 from USB flash drive, but I can boot the USB flash drive from other computers. How can I fix?

Tags: boot, usb

My brand new HP notebook won't boot Ubuntu 12.10 from USB flash drive, but I can boot the USB flash drive from other computers. It will start to load on my notebook but when it gets to the Ubuntu screen it freezes. How can I fix?

Comment: Please edit your question adding information about your notebook, especially your video card.

Comment: Dell laptops have the capability for one-time boot option by depressing f12  perhaps your HP has a similar function

Comment: F10 on my HP desktop enters BIOS set-up

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set your BIOS to boot from USB.

Comment: Please give more detailed instructions.

Comment: We need more than just a one liner that gives no instructions or details. Please, as @lordqwerty said, give more detailed instructions.